# How to count the same values as one sql

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this.

```
----------------------------
| ID | CITY  | BLOCK| NAME |
----------------------------
| 1  |Jakarta|  A   | John |
| 2  |Jakarta|  A   | Rey  |
| 3  |Bekasi |  A   | Boy  |
----------------------------
```

What's the correct query to count total of blocks where the city is Jakarta and if there are the same blocks in Jakarta, the blocks should be counted as one?

```
-----------------------
| TOTAL_BLOCK_JAKARTA | 
-----------------------
|          1          |
-----------------------
```

If I'm using this query,

```
SELECT COUNT(block) FROM member AS total_block_jakarta WHERE city = 'Jakarta' GROUP BY block
```

it will return more than one row like this.

```
-----------------------
| TOTAL_BLOCK_JAKARTA | 
-----------------------
|          1          |
|          1          |  
-----------------------
```

If I'm using `COUNT(DISTINCT)` in above query it will return values like this.

```
-----------------------
| TOTAL_BLOCK_JAKARTA | 
-----------------------
|          2          | 
-----------------------
```

Please help me to find the correct query. Thanks.

Comment: what is `kota`  in your query?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(block)  AS total_block_jakarta FROM member  WHERE CITY = 'Jakarta'

Comment: @Bhansa I'm sorry, kota is city in Bahasa

Comment: you have your column named `city` so you have to `city`

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT block)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT block) AS total_block_jakarta FROM MEMBER WHERE CITY = 'Jakarta';
```

Comment: I think there is no need of `group by` as count is gonna return a single value.

Comment: Your query will return total = 2, I want the same blocks (A) is counted as 1. So the total must be 1

Comment: OH OKAY USE DISTINCT @IrmaElita

Comment: TRY MY UPDATED ANSWER @IrmaElita

Comment: It returns `1` - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a844f/1 - You are probably executing the wrong code.

Comment: DID YOU TRIED MINE QUERY @IrmaElita

Comment: It returns 1 - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a844f/1 - You are probably executing the wrong code. @IrmaElita

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I forgot that in my table Jakarta has two blocks A and B but I just write block A in question to make it simple, so I thought your query is still wrong. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to group the block since you are referring on how many members are on the Jakarta with the same block.

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(block)) FROM member AS total_block_jakarta WHERE kota = 'Jakarta'
```

Comment: It will return 2, I want the same blocks is counted as one

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT BLOCK) AS total_block_jakarta FROM member WHERE CITY LIKE "Jakarta"
```

Output:

```
--------------------
total_block_jakarta
1
---------------------
```

Comment: Your query also returned total = 2

Comment: because there are two cities named "Jakarta"